# Extension not found when running PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit

I try to load an extension to execute my tests with phpunit.

(The extension works in normal php execution)

the extension is defined in php.ini

`extension=v8js.so`

But when I execute my test I have the following error

`Fatal error: Class 'V8Js' not found in helpers/JSBridge.php on line 30`

I tried to force the extension loading with adding `dl("v8js.so");` or `dl("/usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/v8js.so");` in my php test file but still the same error

Comment: The `php.ini` file is different for the web server and CLI. Make sure the extension is added to the command line `php.ini`.

Comment: Thx, it works fine now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The php.ini file is different for the web server and CLI. Make sure the extension is added to the command line php.ini.